# Using Materialized View in a Query and Updating Base Table

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, query-optimization

I am new to oracle and kindly help to answer my question.

I have a materialized view "A_MV" created for a table "A". I have a procedure which will do a SELECT query from the materialzied view "A_MV" and then UPDATE the base table "A" on certain conditions on base table "A".

The SELECT query from "A_MV" is fast, but update to base table is too slow.

Kindly advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Performance is all about data: how much of it and how is it distributed? So the details really matter. Specifically how many rows in the base table? What proportion are you updating? What is the access path for the update? How are you doing the update? What version (and edition) of the database?  Can you post some code?

Comment: Also, what is your definition of "too slow"?

Comment: There is insufficient information in your question. You'll need to provide far more information if people are to help. BTW: What does the Materialized view have to do with it? If you don;t have it, does the update run fast? provide relevant info.

Comment: Sorry for insufficient info in my question. I got help from my friend on this issue. Thanks for your time. Really appreciate that. In future I will make sure i have enough information in my questions. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1):

if mview is set to update on commit then this would force a rebuild of mview every commit.   Also if materialized view log is defined then this can update much more often which would slow it down.

oracle's merge statement is a built in function that is very fast.  Suggest in that case to make sure refresh on mview is set to refresh on demand prior to the merge.  Note you can change it back afterward if you want without rebuilding the mview.